# static declaration in a c++ class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function

I don't understand why the first doesn't work instead the second works!

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include "concurrentQueue.h";
class TestClass {
    public:              
                static concurrentQueue<function<void()>> notW;

                static concurrentQueue<int> Works;
}
```

I attach also the beginning of the concurrentQueue class:

```
template<class Data> class concurrentQueue
```

Comment: If I had known I wouldn't have opened the thread

Comment: I'm not blaming you. :-) I wasn't the one who downvoted your question. I didn't know the answer either. It's just good to keep duplication to a minimum around here. Existing questions are hard enough to find as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a space inside  the `>>` to prevent it from being treated as a right-shift operator:

```
static concurrentQueue<function<void()> > notW;
```

With C++11 compilers this won't be necessary, as the compiler will interpret the angle brackets as closing the template argument list where possible.

Comment: Without a space is allowed since C++11.

Comment: I meant C++11. I'm confused by C99.

Comment: however, if I do that, it isn't inizialized, right? how can I use Works.myFunc() for example?

Answer (score 2):

You need a space between the two closing angle brackets in C++ 03 and earlier. This has been "fixed" in the new 2011 standard.

See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304699/c-templates-angle-brackets-problems) for more information.